# When developing a Xamarin iOS app in Visual Studio on Windows, how much does paired Mac performance influence build and deploy times?

Tags: ios, windows, visual-studio, xamarin

I use a Windows machine to develop in Visual Studio, and I'm paired to the MacBook over a wired network.

I'm considering upgrading my MacBook Air that has a 1.1GHz Quad Core Intel Core i5 processor and 8 GB memory.

Would upgrading the MacBook (I'm considering a MacBook Pro M2 processor, 16 GB memory) have a meaningful impact on build/deploy times of my iOS project in VS on Windows? I'm hesitant to upgrade without knowing this.

Comment: I just upgraded from an Intel to an M2 and the build times aren't significantly faster

Comment: Try using Visual Studio on the Mac while it' still supported

My benchmark Feb 2023

 - Windows with remote simulator (2023 i7 32G, 2TB NVME)
   - Stop, Run to main() 1:10
   - Change project, Run to main() < 3:02
 - Native Mac 2019 i7 32G Visual Studio
   - Stop, Run to main() 0:28
   - Change project, Run to main() < 01:19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting a user on Reddit who responded to my question in two parts:

> The app will take less time to build, and in case you want to debug or
> run it the Simulator will take less time to open, boot iOS and open
> your app.
>
> Deployment to the AppStore Connect portal should take the same time,
> and version approval should not be affected in any way.
>
> It will definitely improve your development environment.

> - The iOS project code is transferred to the Mac over network.
> - Then the code is compiled using Visual Studio for Mac / Mono / Xamarin / Xcode / ¿? on the Mac
>
> Then 3 possible things can happen:
>
> - a) If the iPhone is connected to the Mac, the application is installed from the Mac to the iPhone over USB.
> - b) If the iPhone is connected to the PC, the application is transffered from the Mac to the PC over network, and then is installed
>   in the iPhone over USB.
> - c) If there's no physical iPhone, the application is installed on a simulator instance. Depending on your settings, this Simulator Window
>   can show directly on the Mac, or streamed to the Windows PC over
>   network (with a bit o input lag)
>
> I would say that 70-90% of the deployment process happens on the mac
> side. The PC acts as a remote control only.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Xamarin/comments/14kor20/comment/jprvfum/